# How to leave open the possibility of returning when resigning

Tags: career-development, resignation

I have a good working relationship at my work place. It is a 50-100 person sized company, I have a good relationship with my boss and the CEO. I plan to resign. I love my current job, they've treated me great, but it's the only place I've ever worked. I'd like to explore other opportunities, challenge myself with a new technology stack, possibly move to another city.

That said, I'd be interested in returning to this company in the future. What's the best way to keep this door open? Is it a bad idea to mention this when I'm resigning?

Comment: There isn't much benefit to mentioning the possibility of returning in future (if anything, the fact that you want to leave despite already knowing you'd be interested in returning one day may be frowned upon), it's more about how gracefully you leave.

Comment: @Dukeling that question is more about how to avoid getting a bad reputation, while having no intent to return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saying anything about returning will make it look as though you are trying to have it both ways and quit without really quitting. I do not think it will do anything positive towards getting you rehired.

Instead, you need to quit in such a way that your current manager and colleagues will say very good things about you if asked by their colleagues in the future.

Write a clear but gracious resignation letter. Give proper notice. When notifying your manager of your resignation, talk about all you like about the current company, but explain that you want to explore other opportunities etc. just as you did in the question.

During the notice period, continue to work hard in your employer's interest. Document your work as well as you can etc.

In short, give a very good last impression.